# Using ArcPy GetCount to return number of records for each table in GDB or MDB

Tags: arcpy, arccatalog, count, iteration

This is sample code from Esri

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/data.gdb"
arcpy.GetCount_management("roads")
```

My understanding is this provides the number of records in the table for just the "roads" feature class.

I'm hoping to return the number of records for each feature class and table in the workspace.

Is there a simple way to do so, preferably in ArcCatalog?

Comment: Use ListFeatureClasses, look at the code samples in [the help section](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm)

Comment: This is not the way to count rows, just a small piece of the puzzle. You'll need to research this as well.

Answer (score 3):

This approach uses [`Walk`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm) to list all the featureclasses and tables in a geodatabase and then adds the featureclass/table basename and feature/row [`Count`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm) to a dictionary.

```
import arcpy
import os

# Input workspace
workspace = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb'

# Get a list of all the featureclasses and tables in a geodatabase
feature_classes = []
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype= ["FeatureClass", "Table"])

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

# Get counts and add to dictionary
d = {}
for fc in feature_classes:
    count = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
    d[os.path.basename(fc)] = int(count[0])

# Print featureclass name and  corresponding feature (row) count
print('\n'.join("{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in d.items()))

# Get a total count of features
print("The total count of features and table rows =  {0}".format(sum(d.values())))
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> 
poly1: 97
poly2: 3
poly3: 2
poly4: 5
lines1: 12
lines2: 4
table1: 4
points1: 1
points2: 1
The total count of features and table rows =  129
```